# how to open a gz file if i receive a message data stream error?

Tags: steganography

im trying to solve a task probably from a ctf from an image(png) who found on the web but i stuck very early in this challenge.

i found that the image contain a gz file that i extracted but when i try to open the gz file i got an error:gzip:invalid compressed data--format violated

can someone give me a hint or a solution to this problem?

the original file is:[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sofy9g9mhzvksqu/stego.png?dl=0)

i extracted the gz file from the png image with binwalk

gunzip the gz file gave me an error invalid compressed data--format violated

Answer (score 1):

sounds like the file may not have been properly transferred in binary mode. You might be able to get it to work with unix2dos  but if not, you'll have to try transferring it again, making sure it uses binary mode.

Comment: I was downloading a gzipped file from an FTP server with php and received the same error. This answer actually helped me, my php ftp connection was set to ASCII mode instead of binary.